# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘intsvy’

Tags: r

I am using RStudio Version 1.0.136 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc. I checked for a new update and I received a massege that saying "You're using the newest version of RStudio".

Here I am trying to use R ‘intsvy’ package.

I started by setting up the directory.
Then, first I installed the package by using the following code:

```
install.packages("intsvy", lib="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library")
```

Below is the Console results

```
 There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
intsvy    2.1    2.4             FALSE

installing the source package ‘intsvy’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/intsvy_2.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 56777 bytes (55 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 55 KB

starting R..
* installing *source* package ‘intsvy’ ...
** package ‘intsvy’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘repr’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘intsvy’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/intsvy’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/intsvy’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘intsvy’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/jj/3brk8hp91ps2mdv6gzlynh6r0000gn/T/RtmppVfRws/downloaded_packages’
```

Second, I installed the package by using the following code after receiving the above long massage:

```
install.packages("intsvy")
```

Below is the Console results

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/HU-Hisham/Library/R/3.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
intsvy    2.1    2.4             FALSE

installing the source package ‘intsvy’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/intsvy_2.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 56777 bytes (55 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 55 KB

starting R..
* installing *source* package ‘intsvy’ ...
** package ‘intsvy’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘repr’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘intsvy’
* removing ‘/Users/HU-Hisham/Library/R/3.3/library/intsvy’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘intsvy’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/jj/3brk8hp91ps2mdv6gzlynh6r0000gn/T/RtmppVfRws/downloaded_packages’
```

Next #load backage

```
library("intsvy")
```

Below are the massages I received in the Console

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘repr’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘intsvy’ was built under R version 3.3.2 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘intsvy’
```

After installations, I tried to run the following command

```
pirls.var.label(folder = getwd("~/Desktop/Dr. Kato/Data/PISA/CY07_MSU_STU_QQQ.sav"),
+                 name = "Variable labels", output = getwd())
```

Here is the massage

```
Error: could not find function "pirls.var.label"
```

Function pirls.var.label is one of the functions in the 'intsvy' package.

Why am I receiving this error? Is it because the package not successfully installed? How can I take care or this matter and start using the package and data? Please advice.

I **updated** my R version from R3.3.1 (2016-06-21) to R3.6.2 (2019-12-12)as some experts recommended.

Then I run the commands again after restarting R:

## 1   installing repr package

```
> install.packages("repr")
        Warning in install.packages :
      cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/repr_1.0.2.tgz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 118906 bytes (116 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 116 KB


    The downloaded binary packages are in
        /var/folders/jj/3brk8hp91ps2mdv6gzlynh6r0000gn/T//Rtmpt0mup2/downloaded_packages
    Warning message:
    R graphics engine version 12 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

## 2   installing intsvy package

```
> install.packages("intsvy", dependencies = T)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/intsvy_2.4.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 336356 bytes (328 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 328 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/jj/3brk8hp91ps2mdv6gzlynh6r0000gn/T//Rtmpt0mup2/downloaded_packages
```

## load backage

```
> library("intsvy")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘intsvy’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion("vctrs")
  error: there is no package called ‘vctrs’
> library(intsvy)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘intsvy’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion("vctrs")
  error: there is no package called ‘vctrs’
```

Still same errors when I try to run the package commands

```
> pisa.var.lable(folder="~/Desktop/Dr. Kato/Data/PISA/CY07_MSU_STU_QQQ.sav")
Error in pisa.var.lable(folder = "~/Desktop/Dr. Kato/Data/PISA/CY07_MSU_STU_QQQ.sav") : 
  could not find function "pisa.var.lable"
> pirls.var.label(folder = getwd("~/Desktop/Dr. Kato/Data/PISA/CY07_MSU_STU_QQQ.sav"),
+                 name = "Variable labels", output = getwd())
Error in pirls.var.label(folder = getwd("~/Desktop/Dr. Kato/Data/PISA/CY07_MSU_STU_QQQ.sav"),  : 
  could not find function "pirls.var.label"
```

If you have an idea, please share it here so I can try it to solve this issue and start using the package and PISA data.

Thank you

Comment: The error message says: `there is no package called ‘repr’`. Try to install `repr` package: `install.packages("repr")`

Comment: First you install the package `repr`, then install the `intsvy` package. Or you can use `install.packages("intsvy", dependencies = T)`.

Comment: Thanks, dear Marco and Bappa for your quick comments. I installed the 'repr' package and the installed "intsvy", but still the same issues and massages. The author of "intsvy" package just replied to my email and said what you all said. But he asked me "what is your devtools::session_info()?" and I tried [session_info("devtools")] where I got the following error [Error: could not find function "session_info"]

Comment: You should use `sessionInfo("devtools")` or `devtools::session_info("devtools")`

Comment: Thanks again Marco. I did use both packages you suggested and run the following `pirls.var.label(folder = getwd("~/Desktop/Dr. Kato/Data/PISA/CY07_MSU_STU_QQQ.sav"),
                name = "Variable labels", output = getwd())` Here is the massage from the console `Error in getwd("~/Desktop/Dr. Kato/Data/PISA/CY07_MSU_STU_QQQ.sav") : 
  unused argument ("~/Desktop/Dr. Kato/Data/PISA/CY07_MSU_STU_QQQ.sav")` I will keep trying, so if you have other ideas please share.

Comment: You could also try the `RALSA` package which has a graphical user interface: https://cran.r-project.org/package=RALSA For guides on how to use it, see here: http://ralsa.ineri.org/user-guide/